# Как уменьшить вес сборки в CLion

Tags: c++

Здравстуйте. Есть необходимость собрать проект весом не более 1 мб, но 1 класс в проекте весит около 13мб. Так вот, что я могу сделать, что бы exe у меня был весом не более 1 мб?

Comment: какие компилятор/ос?

Comment: Vladimir, MinGW and win10

Comment: "1 класс в проекте весит около 13мб" - что бы это значило?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLion 2017.3, msys64/mingw32, w64 5.0, тестовый проект с одним классом:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    void bar() {
        std::cout << "bar\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

После сборки на выходе получаем исполняемый файл размером 379кб.

Добавляем (в CMakeLists.txt) флажок компилятора `-s` (убирает символы из исполняемого файла, отлаживать станет проблематично):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -s")
```

После сборки получаем исполняемый файл размером 17кб.

Упаковываем полученный exe с помощью [UPX](https://upx.github.io/):

```
upx.exe foo.exe
```

Получаем исполняемый файл размером всего 9кб.

Дополнительно можно задать компилятору ключ оптимизации по размеру: `-Os`, но для этого простого примера разница была несущественной.

Comment: Еще неплохо работает `-flto` (прописывать и линкеру, и компилятору).